# How to make Process.Start a blocking call?

Tags: c#, process, blocking

I have a call to `Process.Start()` which runs a third party exe. I need to process the output files of this executable so I want the call to Process.Start() to be blocking.

Is it possible to change this call to a blocking call?

```
Process sampleProcess= new Process();
sampleProcess.StartInfo = sampleProcessInfoObject;
sampleProcess.Start();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Process.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.

> Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the
>   associated process to exit.

You would use it like this:

```
Process sampleProcess= new Process();
sampleProcess.StartInfo = sampleProcessInfoObject;
sampleProcess.Start();
sampleProcess.WaitForExit(); // Will wait indefinitely until the process exits
```

Comment: An easy way: `Process process = Process.Start("explorer");
process.WaitForExit();`

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to specify anything (leave everything at default) - then you don't need a `ProcessStartInfo` object. I used one in this answer because the OP used one in their snippet.